# Custom module field displays twice when adding content

Tags: entities

I've created a module consisting of 5 fields. I've set the number of values unlimited, and when I do, 2 of the custom fields are displayed (see image). How can I get a default of 1 custom field type to display?

[image]

This is the .module:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);    

include 'cloudinary/src/Cloudinary.php';
include 'cloudinary/src/Uploader.php';
include 'cloudinary/src/Api.php';    

$cloud_name = variable_get('cloudinary_cloud_name');
$api_key = variable_get('cloudinary_api_key');
$api_secret = variable_get('cloudinary_api_secret');
$api_url = variable_get('cloudinary_editor_url');    

function cloudinary_menu() {
    $items['admin/config/cloudinary'] = array(
        'title' => 'Cloudinary',
        'description' => 'Interact with cloudinary.',
        'position' => 'right',
        'weight' => -5,
        'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
        'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
        'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
        'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
    );
    $items['admin/config/cloudinary/settings'] = array(
        'title' => 'Cloudinary settings',
        'description' => 'Configure cloudinary.',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('cloudinary_admin_settings'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'file' => 'cloudinary.admin.inc',
    );
    return $items;
}    

/**
 * Implements hook_field_info().
 * define the field type
 */
function cloudinary_field_info() {
    return array(
        'cloudinary' => array(
            'label' => t('Cloudinary image selector'),
            'description' => t('Search for images and select one for display.'),
            'default_widget' => 'cloudinary_widget',
            'default_formatter' => 'cloudinary_formatter',
            'settings' => array(),
            'instance_settings' => array(),
        )
    );
}
/**
* This is the "Field type" dropdown
*/
function cloudinary_field_widget_info() {
    return array(
        'cloudinary_widget' => array(
            'label' => t('Default'),
            'field types' => array('cloudinary'),
        )
    );
}    

/**
*/
function cloudinary_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $lang, $items, $delta, $element) {    

    //TODO: this is temporary! Need to figure out how to pull it in properly
    //this sets the finder url to the service i.e. localhost or whatever
    drupal_add_js(array('cloudinary' => array('finderUrl' => variable_get('cloudinary_editor_url'))), 'setting');
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'cloudinary') . '/assets/js/cloudinary.js');
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'cloudinary') . '/assets/css/cloudinary.css');    

    $item =& $items[$delta];    

    $element['publicID'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Public ID'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#default_value' => isset($item['publicID']) ? $item['publicID'] : '',
    );    

    $element['url'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Url'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#default_value' => isset($item['url']) ? $item['url'] : '',
    );    

    $element['title'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Title'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#default_value' => isset($item['title']) ? $item['title'] : '',
    );    

    $element['caption'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Caption'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#default_value' => isset($item['caption']) ? $item['caption'] : '',
    );    

    $element['alt'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Alt'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#default_value' => isset($item['alt']) ? $item['alt'] : '',
    );    

    $element['credit'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Credit'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#default_value' => isset($item['credit']) ? $item['credit'] : '',
    );    

    $element['ajax_button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#attributes' => array( 'class' => array( 'cloudinary_browse ctools-use-modal') ),
        '#value' => t('Search cloudinary'),
    );    

    return $element;
}    

function cloudinary_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
    $valid = TRUE;
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if(empty($value)) {
            $valid = FALSE;
        }
    }
    return $valid;
}    

function cloudinary_field_validate($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, &$errors) {    

    //in case we want to validate fields
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        if (!isset($item['publicID']) ||
            !isset($item['url']) ||
            !isset($item['title']) ||
            !isset($item['caption']) ||
            !isset($item['alt']) ||
            !isset($item['credit'])) {    

            $errors[$field['field_name']][$langcode][$delta][] = array(
                'error' => 'cloudinary_fields_missing',
                'message' => t('%title: Make sure all fields are completed. '.
                    'Make sure all fiends are entered.',
                    array('%title' => $instance['label'])
                ),
            );
        }
    }    

}    

function cloudinary_field_widget_error($element, $error, $form, &$form_state) {
    switch ($error['error']) {
        case 'cloudinary_fields_missing':
            form_error($element, $error['message']);
            break;
    }
}    

/**
This appears in the widget dropdown
*/
function cloudinary_field_formatter_info() {
    return array(
        'cloudinary_formatter' => array(
            'label' => t('Cloudinary selector'),
            'field types' => array('cloudinary'),
        )
    );
}    

function cloudinary_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
    $element = array();
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        $element[$delta] = cloudinary_format_field($item);
    }
    return $element;
}    

function cloudinary_format_field($item) {    

    $item = array('url' => $item['url'], 
        'title' => $item['title'], 
        'caption' => $item['caption'], 
        'alt' => $item['alt'], 
        'credit' => $item['credit']);    

    $element['url'] = array(
        'item' => array(
            '#type' => 'container',
            '#attributes' => array( 'class' => array( 'field-item') ),
            'text' => array(
              '#markup' => generate_image($item)
            ),
        ),
    );    

    return $element;
}    

function generate_image ($item) {    

    $fields = array(
        '@url' => substr_replace($item['url'], '/c_limit,h_250,w_250', strripos($item['url'], "/"), 0), 
        '@title' => $item['title'], 
        '@caption' => $item['caption'], 
        '@alt' => $item['alt'], 
        '@credit' => $item['credit'], 
    );    

    $image = t('<figure><img src="@url" alt="@alt"><figcaption><h1>@title</h1><p>@caption @credit</p></figcaption></figure>', $fields);    

    return $image;
}
```

This is the .info:

```
name = Cloudinary
description = Interact with your cloudinary account.
core = 7.x
package = Cloudinary
files[] = cloudinary.test
configure = admin/config/cloudinary
```

This is the .install:

```
<?php
/**
* Implements hook_install()
*/    

function cloudinary_field_schema($field) {    

  $columns = array(
    'publicID' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 255, 'not null' => FALSE),
    'url' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 255, 'not null' => FALSE),
    'title' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 255, 'not null' => FALSE),
    'caption' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 255, 'not null' => FALSE),
    'alt' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 255, 'not null' => FALSE),
    'credit' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 255, 'not null' => FALSE));    

  return array(
    'columns' => $columns
  );    

}
```

Comment: can you verify how many times cloudinary_field_formatter_view actually runs, and what $display holds when it does?

Comment: @Geoff I just checked, it doesn't look like it is running in the admin screen, but it does when I create some content and view it. I added "error_log("in cloudinary_field_formatter_view");" but nothing is appearing in the log file.

Comment: ok - looks like there's a viable answer anyways - I was working on a hunch that I don't think is the cause now.

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10481/unlimited-values-field-how-to-hide-extra-field-on-node-edit

Comment: @justinelejeune thanks! It looks like a bit of a hack, but if that is a fix then maybe thats the way forward :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is in the way of checking empty values

```
function cloudinary_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
    $valid = TRUE;
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if(empty($value)) {
            $valid = FALSE;
        }
    }
    return $valid;
}
```

Make sure you're not checking for extra elements, a quick test would be to check for each element:

```
return empty($item['url']) && empty($item['title']) && empty($item['caption']) && empty($item['alt']) && empty($item['credit']);
```

Comment: Apologies, I was sure I fixed it by changing the .info file, as I was setting files[] twice. However, on trying again the issues is back :'(

Comment: @MarkRobson +1 for this as an answer - I think the field instance's default value is considered non-empty. After making this code change don't forget to edit the field and resave to update the default value.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick :) Thanks @pcambra and thanks to Andy

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, You have to remove the last element manually. I haven't found a better solution yet. Achieving this for a 'node' form is easy, about other entity types, I don't really know if there is a proper general hook. There should be a hook for modules using Entity API...

Anyway here is how it's done, I've tested it with your module and it works. Also note this code is not specific to any particular field, You could use it as a general site-wide module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_NODE_FORM_alter().
 */
function cloudinary_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$fs) {
  foreach (array_keys($form) as $fname) {
    // Pull out field API form elements.
    if (substr($fname, 0, 6) != "field_" || empty($form[$fname])) {
      continue;
    }

    // Use field's own language not to break multilingual installations.
    $lang = $form[$fname]['#language'];

    // Decrease delta by one and get rid of the last delta;
    $max_delta = $form[$fname][$lang]['#max_delta']--;
    unset($form[$fname][$lang][$max_delta]);
  }
}
```

PS: If it broke anything you can remove the `foreach` and use a callback and see if this behavior is enabled for this particular field instance/type.
You can then add some extra configuration to all the fields with related hooks: `Enable cloudy last delta remover for this field?` but ofcourse with a more site-admin not-very-technical friendly description.

Comment: So this issue is common in Drupal? I did quite an extensive search but can't find this happening to others much?

Comment: Most importantly this does not happen to core's fields and I don't know why. Date field has this issue (Most of the times but not always).
the solution is from somewhere in D.O which I can't find the link unfortunately.

Comment: @MarkRobson and about the validate function: if you meant to make sure user has provided all the values, you validation hook is wrong, it should use empty(...) because isset(...) always returns true.
Also you might want to put your field's elements in a function like _cloudinary_field_elements() {return array(...);} and use it in foreach's like the one in validation hook.
This is worthy of note to say you might want to add 'property_callbacks' to field_info(), look at addressfield module, this is done for the sake of views, rules, ... (entity API)